# Spellcheck on Website - multiple fields

Tags: design, grid, popup, spell-checking

I have a site with a page that contains multiple editable fields with html values. User can click in them and edit the text inside them.

Note that the fields are present in a grid with PAGER.

For spellcheck functionality-

### **Option 1**

Should I show the incorrect words marked up and let them correct the spellings word by word? 
Issues in this method:

- This requires user to page through to see all incorrect words
- Also, it is not possible to give 'correct all occurrences'/'ignore all occurrences'

### **Option 2**

Show a list of incorrect words in a pop-up and let them correct the spellings from the list?

How can I decide which way to go?

Comment: Why not use the built in spell checker that is already available in most browsers?

Comment: Html5 spellcheck implementation is different for different browsers. Also, my editors are html editors, html5 spellcheck doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I think most users want to see in what context they made a typo, and want to rearead it to make sure it was not the system that false reported it. I wouldn't go for option 2.

You could go for option 1 and provide an extra check after proceeding (saving, editing, whatever your application does) in case a spelling mistake was found; asking the user to edit this list of words.

The program could automatically slide to each spelling mistake like in Word or Indesign spellcheck software.

**If I had to pick one of your given options**, I'd choose option 1 because it gives broader feedback to the user.

Answer (score 1):

In combination to option 1, you could mark the pager-items that link to pages with typo's in them. For example:

```
1  [ 2 ]  [ 3 ] [ 4* ] [ 5 ] [ 6* ]
```

Where page 4 and 6 still have unrevised errors.